# Syntax Error - unexpected identifier (XMPP with Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, xmpp

Syntax Error - unexpected identifier XMPP with Node

I'm new to Node and XMPP and I get errors when reading the chat stanza with ltx the error is:.

```
const logEntry = 'Received message from ' ${from} ' with ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

at createScript (vm.js:56:10) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10) at Module._compile (module.js:542:28) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10) at Module.load (module.js:487:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10) at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7) at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

The file name is: index.js

Here is the code:

```
    const Client = require('node-xmpp-client')
, ltx = Client.ltx
const options = {
jid: 'bot@localhost',
password: 'tellnoone'
}
const client = new Client(options)
client.on('online', (connectionDetails) => {
console.log('We are connected!')
console.log(connectionDetails)
sendPresence()
})
const sendPresence = () => {
var stanza = new ltx.Element('presence')
console.log('Sending presence: ' + stanza.toString())
client.send(stanza)
}
client.on('stanza', (stanza) => {
if (false === stanza.is('message')) return /* Not a <message/> stanza */
const messageContent = stanza.getChildText('body')
if (!messageContent) return /* Not a chat message */
const from = stanza.attr('from')
const logEntry = 'Received message from ' ${from} ' with
content:\n${messageContent}'
console.log(logEntry)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line

`const logEntry = 'Received message from ' ${from} ' with
content:\n${messageContent}'`

to

`` const logEntry = `Received message from ${from} with content:\n ${messageContent}` ``

Template strings use backtick instead of quote.